# Animated Path is getting cut off

Tags: c#, wpf

Iam trying to made an animated Path which is suppossed to seem infinite.
The Path is drawn ontop of a Button, but the Problem is that when the Path is moving you cant see all of the Path, it just cuts of at the width of the Button.
To demonstrate here is a Picture:
[image: The red border is from Snoop, which shows the correct size of the Path-Element]
The Path is very simple, there are 10 diagonal lines side by side.

The StoryBoard:

```
   <Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardPath" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
      <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:0:1" 
                              Source="X" 
                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                              Storyboard.TargetName="pathTranslateTranform">
         <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M-120,0 L0,0"/>
         </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
      </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
   </Storyboard>
```

And the Datatemplate for the Buttons:

```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type controls:Button}">
      <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
         <Button Content="Test Button"/>
         <Path x:Name="busyIndicator"
               Fill="Brown">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
               <TransformGroup>
                  <TranslateTransform x:Name="pathTranslateTranform"/>
               </TransformGroup>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
            <Path.Data>
               M 0 0   l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
               M 40 0  l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
               M 80 0  l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
               M 120 0 l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
               M 160 0 l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
               M 200 0 l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
               M 240 0 l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
               M 280 0 l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
               M 320 0 l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
               M 360 0 l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
               M 400 0 l 20 0   l 80 100   l -20 0 z
            </Path.Data>
         </Path>
      </Grid>

      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy.Value}" Value="False">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
               <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                     <StaticResource ResourceKey="StoryboardPath"/>
                  </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
         </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
   </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: A DataTemplate for a Button doesn't seem to make sense, because a Button is not "data". Besides that, why is there `ClipToBounds="True"` on the Grid? What if you remove that, or set it to false?

Comment: ClipToBounds doesnt change the Size of the Path at all unfortunately, just let it clip outside of the Grid Area.
Here is an gif showing that off: https://i.imgur.com/XmhJ866.gifv

Comment: What i just found out with Snoop is that the DesiredSize is set to the size of the Grid/Button, if i change that the Button size gets bigger but also the Path too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution I found:
Putting a negative Margin-value for the right side fixes the problem.
So this works for me:

```
<Path x:Name="busyIndicator"
        Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"
        Fill="Red"
        Opacity="0.2"
        Margin="0,0,-160,0">
...
</Path>
```

And if it interests anyone, to make the animation seamless, I had to adjust the StoryBoard.
Replace the one on the top with:

```
<PathGeometry Figures="M-160,0 L-80,0"/>
```

Result looks like this:
[image: Solution]

and here is it as a gif, showing how the animation looks:
https://i.imgur.com/TrrhboT.gifv